# How can i inject dynamic value into interface in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring and Kotlin for my web app.

```
@Mapper
@Repository
interface MyEntityMapper {
    /**
     * Поиск MyEntity.
     *
     * @param selectStatement Параметры запроса.
     * @return List MyEntity.
     */
    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    @Results(
        id = "myEntityMap",
        value = [
            Result(property = "name", column = "NAME"),
            Result(property = "price", column = "PRICE"),
            Result(property = "age", column = "AGE")
        ]
    )
    fun findListBy(selectStatement: SelectStatementProvider): List<MyEntity>

    /**
     * Обновление MyEntity.
     *
     * @param updateStatement MyEntity
     * @return Количество обновленных записей.
     */
    @UpdateProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "update")
    fun update(updateStatement: UpdateStatementProvider): Int
}

fun MyEntityMapper.selectMany(completer: SelectCompleter) =
    selectList(this::findListBy, myEntity_.all, myEntity, completer)

fun MyEntityMapper.update(completer: UpdateCompleter) =
    update(this::update, MyEntity_, completer)
```

myEntity_ is a simple class, not component.

```
class MyEntity_ : SqlTable("my_entity") {
    val name = column<String>(name = "NAME", jdbcType = VARCHAR)
    val price = column<String>(name = "PRICE", jdbcType = VARCHAR)
    val age = column<String>(name = "AGE", jdbcType = VARCHAR)

    val all = listOf(
        name,
        price,
        age
    )

    companion object {
        val myEntity_ = MyEntity_()
    }
}
```

A problem is on *class MyEntity_ : SqlTable("my_entity")*

*my_entity* is a constant String.

**Is it possible to use dynamic variable (maybe values from application.properties) insted hardcode value?**

Comment: The only way I am aware of is Value annotation but that requires MyEntity_  to be a Component or via Autowired + Bean defn

Answer (score 0):

Finally!
I found the solution to my problem.

First I was create a simple config bean:

```
@Configuration
class TableNameConfig(
    @Value("\${tableName.myEntity}") val myEntity: String,

    @Value("\${tableName.table2}") val table2: String,

    @Value("\${tableName.table3}") val table3: String
)
```

Than i add that to my application.properties file:

```
tableName.myEntity=my_entity
tableName.table2=table2
tableName.table3=some_table_name
```

Because I have spring-boot application, I can get appContext like this:

```
@Component
class ApplicationContextProvider : ApplicationContextAware {
    @Throws(BeansException::class)
    override fun setApplicationContext(ac: ApplicationContext) {
        applicationContext = ac
    }

    companion object {
        var applicationContext: ApplicationContext? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

After that I modify my entity class:

```
class MyEntity_(tableName: String) : SqlTable(tableName) {
    val name = column<String>(name = "NAME", jdbcType = VARCHAR)
    val price = column<String>(name = "PRICE", jdbcType = VARCHAR)
    val age = column<String>(name = "AGE", jdbcType = VARCHAR)

    val all = listOf(
        name,
        price,
        age
    )

    companion object {
        fun myEntity(): MyEntity_ {
            val config: TableNameConfig = ApplicationContextProvider.applicationContext?.getBean("tableNameConfig",TableNameConfig::class.java)
                        ?: throw Exception()
                return MyEntity_(config.myEntity)
            }
        }
```

}

And finally i was update two methods in MyEntityMapper where i call MyEntity:

```
fun MyEntityMapper.selectMany(completer: SelectCompleter) =
    selectList(this::findListBy, myEntity().all, dcsMedia(), completer)

fun MyEntityMapper.update(completer: UpdateCompleter) =
    update(
        this::update,
        myEntity(),
        completer
    )
```

It works for me. And now i can configurate naming of myTableForm property file!